# ServiceStack Razor Engine not rendering Layout (_Layout.cshtml)

Tags: iis, servicestack, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I've been trying to deploy a quite simple website based on ServiceStack with Razor view engine to a newly installed Windows Server 2012 box.

It works fine on my Win 7 developer machine, but once on win 2012 iis 8 this happens:

GET /Home : Renders and returns just my Homes.cshtml view, with no sign of my _Layout.cshtml, so no stylesheets or scripts are loaded.

GET /Customers : Nothing. Just the "standard" ServiceStack page. No sign of either Customers.cshtml or _Layout.cshtml

GET /System : Renders and returns my Systems.cshtml, no sign of my _Layout.cshtml

Anyone got an idea?

Seems configuration of iis8 might not be all that compatible with my iis7 developer configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Visual Studio did not pack all the views correctly in the publish package. A little fiddling with the build actions and it worked fine. Some of the views had build action "None", while others had "Content". (So much hassle for so little)